# Is there any function from time.h that sets internal buffer

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
    int main() 
{
    time_t time1, time2;
    struct tm *timeinfo1, *timeinfo2;
    char *time1str, *time2str;


    time1 = 3600;
    time2 = 3720;

    // here i must insert function from time.h

    ///////////////////////////
    timeinfo1 = localtime(&time1);// here
    localtime(&time2);

    time1str = new char [strlen(asctime(timeinfo1)) + 2];
    strcpy(time1str, asctime(timeinfo1));
    timeinfo2 = localtime(&time2);
    time2str = asctime(timeinfo2);
    puts(time1str);
    puts(time2str);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any function that i can insert between slash comments to set internal buffer.? This buffer erase my previous value.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be C, proper. Don't mix C and C++ in the way you do it, these are two different languages. In particular don't compile C code with a C++ compiler, semantics can be slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with C only. In C including C99 there was no such function. C11 now has a function `localtime_s` that is part of the *optional* bounds checking extension:

```
struct tm *localtime_s(const time_t * restrict timer, struct tm * restrict result);
```

Unfortunately, there are not many platforms that implement that extension yet.

POSIX has a `localtime_r` function with exactly the same interface and similar semantics. To capture this kind of system and remain portable you could do something like

```
#ifdef _XOPEN_SOURCE
# define localtime_s localtime_r
#endif
```

or if you want to have it closer to the additional guarantees that `localtime_s` is supposed to give

```
#ifdef _XOPEN_SOURCE
struct tm *localtime_s(const time_t * restrict timer, struct tm * restrict result) {
   return (timer && result ? localtime_r(timer, result) : 0);
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. What you're looking for is the reentrant version of `localtime()`: `localtime_r()`. It works exactly like `localtime()`, except it writes its results into a buffer you supply as an argument instead of to a static buffer. The prototype is:

```
 struct tm *
 localtime_r(const time_t *clock, struct tm *result);
```

Usage in your application would look like:

```
struct tm timeinfo1, timeinfo2;
...
localtime_r(&time1, &timeinfo1);
localtime_r(&time2, &timeinfo2);
```

Comment: `localtime_r` is not part of the C standard